# Azure ssh to web app failed: AppServiceTunnel/Tunnel.ashx?GetStatus' with status code '404' and reason 'Not Found'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I need to `ssh` to a `Web App` on `Azure`. Following the [instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/05/07/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-ssh/) I installed the `azure cli`, logged in, and called to open the tunnel:

```
az webapp remote-connection create -g myresourcegroup -n myapp -p 9000
```

It generates this error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/.azure/cliextensions/webapp/azext_webapp/custom.py", line 235, in _start_tunnel
if not _check_for_ready_tunnel(remote_debugging_enabled, tunnel_server):
  File "/Users/myusername/.azure/cliextensions/webapp/azext_webapp/custom.py", line 200, in _check_for_ready_tunnel
default_port = tunnel_server.is_port_set_to_default()
  File "/Users/myusername/.azure/cliextensions/webapp/azext_webapp/tunnel.py", line 96, in is_port_set_to_default
url, r.status, r.reason))
knack.util.CLIError: Failed to connect to 'https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/AppServiceTunnel/Tunnel.ashx?GetStatus' with status code '404' and reason 'Not Found'
```

How do I go from here? I'm on `MacOs`.

EDIT:

A few lines of the `debug` trace before the error:

```
msrest.http_logger : <publishData><publishProfile profileName="hxserver1 - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" publishUrl="hxserver1.scm.azurewebsites.net:443" msdeploySite="hxserver1" userName="$hxserver1" userPWD="bRqeRL3xwe1K2Wuqi3MX6oFZMlASg3jSt3bE9lN4YygiNafTvJSrgbTNMLz1" destinationAppUrl="http://hxserver1.azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites"><databases /></publishProfile><publishProfile profileName="hxserver1 - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod-blu-083.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot" ftpPassiveMode="True" userName="hxserver1\$hxserver1" userPWD="bRqeRL3xwe1K2Wuqi3MX6oFZMlASg3jSt3bE9lN4YygiNafTvJSrgbTNMLz1" destinationAppUrl="http://hxserver1.azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites"><databases /></publishProfile></publishData>
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): hxserver1.scm.azurewebsites.net
urllib3.connectionpool : https://hxserver1.scm.azurewebsites.net:443 "GET /api/settings HTTP/1.1" 200 574
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): hxserver1.scm.azurewebsites.net
urllib3.connectionpool : https://hxserver1.scm.azurewebsites.net:443 "GET /AppServiceTunnel/Tunnel.ashx?GetStatus HTTP/1.1" 404 67
```

Comment: The az webapp remote-connection can work on my Windows 10 desktop with putty. Have you tried to install the latest CLI and set the subscription and resource group that your current web app belongs to? Could you try to add --debug to see more information?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT I added some debug lines to the question. The whole trace is hundreds or more lines, and seem like it has no errors. Is there another way to `ssh` to the machine? I need it to work from my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there another way to ssh to the machine? I need it to work from my
>   mac.

For your comment, you really want to know how to SSH to your website, you could click "SSH" on your web app service page on the Azure portal.

[image]

About your question, It seems that there are some CLI error "CLIError: Failed to connect to KUDU site with status code '404' and reason 'Not Found'" when you use `az webapp remote-connection` to create a TCP tunnel, not actual errors on your side. You can also use SSH on the portal to access your web app Linux container.

In a Public Preview, for a given app we only support a single TCP tunnel at any given time. We plan to remove this limitation in future releases after Public Preview. Refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/05/07/remotedebugginglinux/).

With the preview version, there might some uncomfortable experiences of SSH. You could look at a similar open scenario on [github](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2683).

Comment: Cool. On my portal it says `Console` instead of `ssh` but it does the same. You don't directly answer the question but I'll accept it because the solution you suggest is quite a bit simpler.

Comment: Glad this helps.